# クラスにメソッドを追加したい

Tags: python, python3

以前作ったクラスに新しくメソッドを追加したいのですが上手くいきません。
目的は新しくdraw_barというメソッドをつかってグラフを書きたいと考えています。

［以前作ったもの］

```
import turtle

class Kame(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("turtle")
        self.shapesize(2,2)
```

［追加したいメソッド］

```
def draw_bar(self,height,width=40):
    self.left(90)
    self.fd(height)
    self.right(90)
    self.fd(width)
    self.right(90)
    self.fd(height)
    self.left(90)
```

［ターミナルでの実行コード］

```
import kame
>>> hist_kame=kame.Kame()
>>> hist_kame.draw_bar(120)
```

［エラー］
AttributeError: 'Kame' object has no attribute 'draw_bar'

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「上手くいきません」というのは、何が起きていて、何で困っているというのですか？

Comment: 失礼いたしました。エラーコードを追記しました。

Comment: `draw_bar` メソッドは、ちゃんとインデントして追加しましたか?

Comment: はい、インデントして追加しました。

Comment: draw_barメソッドが追加される前のkameクラスのファイル(旧ファイル)と、draw_barメソッドを追加した後のkameクラスのファイル(新ファイル)があって、旧ファイルのほうがimportされているのではないかと思われます。kameクラスのファイルの所在と、pythonのimportパスを確認してみてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import turtle

class Kame(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("turtle")
        self.shapesize(2,2)

    def draw_bar(self,height,width=40):
        self.left(90)
        self.fd(height)
        self.right(90)
        self.fd(width)
        self.right(90)
        self.fd(height)
        self.left(90)
```

上のようにすべきとことろで、次のようにしているのではないでしょうか。

```
import turtle

class Kame(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("turtle")
        self.shapesize(2,2)

def draw_bar(self,height,width=40):
    self.left(90)
    self.fd(height)
    self.right(90)
    self.fd(width)
    self.right(90)
    self.fd(height)
    self.left(90)
```

前者はクラス内に定義したメソッドなので、`hist_kame.draw_bar(120)`のように呼び出せますが、後者はクラスの外に定義した関数なので、それができないため、`AttributeError`がスローされたんだと思います。

Comment: コードは前者の形で書いております。ちなみに上記のコードをコピペさせていただいて実行致しましたが、同じエラーコードが出ます。

Comment: @Yuki `self.shapesize(2,2)`と`def draw_bar(self,height,width=40):`の間の改行（1行）を消して、実行してみたらどうなりますか？

Comment: 改行を消して実行したところ、次のようなエラーが出ました。Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Sawaii/pythonworks/kame.py", line 5, in __init__
    super().__init__()

Comment: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 3816, in __init__
    visible=visible)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 2557, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()

Comment: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator

Comment: @Yuki うーん、今実際に試してみましたが、私の環境では亀が動きますね。`vi /Users/Sawaii/pythonworks/kame.py`の結果とPythonのバージョンを質問に追記してもらえますか？

Comment: pythonのバージョンは3.6.5です。理由は解明出来ていませんが、新たに.pyファイルを作ってコードを書き写して実行したところ亀がちゃんと動きました。ありがとうございました。（少しモヤモヤしますが、とりあえずどんどんコードを書いてがむしゃらにまずは荒削りでも学びます。）いつも感謝です。